# How can one display multiple overlaid lines?

Tags: graph, stata

I'm working in Stata 13.1. Is there any way to plot 3 different predicted_responses (with different colour) for every hour (24,48,72), in the same plot? With my code I receive 3 graphs but I want only one.

My code:

```
gr7 predicted_response Response Concentration if Hours==24, xlab ylab c(l.) s(iO)
gr7 predicted_response Response Concentration if Hours==48, xlab ylab c(l.) s(iO)
gr7 predicted_response Response Concentration if Hours==72, xlab ylab c(l.) s(iO)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly literal translation, with some extra bells and whistles.

```
line predicted_response Concentration if Hours==24, lc(red) sort 
|| line predicted_response Concentration if Hours==48, lc(blue) sort 
|| line predicted_response Concentration if Hours==72, lc(black) sort 
|| scatter Response Concentration if Hours==24, mc(red) 
|| scatter Response Concentration if Hours==48, mc(blue)
|| scatter Response Concentration if Hours==72, mc(black) 
legend(order(4 "24 hours" 5 "48 hours" 6 "72 hours")) 
ytitle(Observed and predicted response)
```

Note also the `separate` command and what it allows.

Comment: Thanks for replying mate!  I receive something like that !https://ibb.co/2c8XKbL . The max Concentration value is 100 so it doesn't make sense. This is the output with gr7 but only at 48 hours !https://ibb.co/02YGBkC . So I would like to see 3 different predicted_response for each hour. Thanks again

Comment: I can't see a problem with my code, or if you think there is one you need to produce a reproducible example so that we can compare. That is standard advice for SO.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Your problem is that your distribution of concentration is so skewed that the graph doesn't make much obvious sense, either scientifically or statistically. You could post your data and problem elsewhere (e.g. Statalist or Cross Validated) but not liking the graph is not a Stata programming issue.

Comment: Your second link doesn't work for me. As said, I can't see the data but it may be that you should work with log concentration or omit the outlier if it is not credible.

Answer (score 0):

```
twoway scatter x y if z == 1, c(L) || ///
       scatter x y if z == 2, c(L) || ///
       scatter x y if z == 3, c(L) || ///
```

`gr7` is not compatible with `twoway` but you should be able to use `scatter` or `line` instead.

Note: `gr7` is an outdated Stata command that you shouldn't rely on; learn to use the standard graphing commands; see `help graph`.

Comment: This draws the lines wanted by the OP, but doesn't show the data points in a scatter.